# Backup Failed: Could not understand duplicity version + Cannot ask duplicity for its version

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I get the following error when trying to run backup on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04:
[image]

I also get the following error when trying to ask duplicity for its version:

```
xyz@thinkpad:~$ deja-dup --version
deja-dup 37.0
xyz@thinkpad:~$ duplicity --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 49, in <module>
    from duplicity import collections
ImportError: cannot import name collections
```

I've tried to reinstall duplicity in two ways, but neither fixes any of the two errors so I think the error must lie elsewhere:

1. apt remove duplicity && apt install duplicity
2. rm /usr/bin/duplicity && apt remove duplicity && apt install duplicity

Does anybody know what could cause an error like that? Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Duplicity. Use the *rsync* command for backing up data files, or easier still its [front-end GUI, Grsync](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4M1-4Fe98I8&t=23s).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with using rsync (or Grsync) commands and having problems with Duplicity, then use LuckyBackup downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

It uses the rysnc command set but in a much more user friendly fashion with the added advantage that you can try out your selections first before committing them to a final run. Not only that but you can schedule backups to make life much more simple.

I have been using this for some time now backing up various drives (including a NAS) and backups can be made to cloud based storage (such as DropBox).

Comment: Does not answer the question. I have the same problem. My backup archive was made in using Backup (duplicity). Changing backup methods is a useless answer.